# Automatic insertion of empty line in Java source on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to format Java source on Eclipse below,

```java
public void myDoSth() {

// [Rule 1] 1 empty line above, at beginning of method body
// ...
// [Rule 2] 1 empty line below, at end of method body

}
```

`Rule 1` above can be configured with `project->properties->Java Code Style->Formatter->Blank Lines->At beginning of method body`.

How about `Rule 2`? Is it configurable on Eclipse, too?

In general, is it feasible to automatically insert empty line `after open brace {` or `before close brace }` in Java source on Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

**Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Code Style** -> **Formatter** -> Edit a profile -> **White Spaces** -> **Declarations** -> **Methods** -> Save your new profile.

Comment: `Empty line` than `White space` is needed.

Comment: You have the tab `Blank lines`, and a checkbox called `At beginning of method body`. Automatically putting and extra line at the *end* of the method body is silly.